# c++ ofstream keeps failing member function

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have made a program, where I want to write some things on a file. When I do it directly from my main-function it works fine, but when i make this class member function, it fails to do that. std::cout works without a problem, and I don't receive any error message. It just doesn't write on the file. This is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
... // not relevant
template <class T>
void Grid <T>::write() const {
    int printcount = 0;
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("data.txt", ios::app);
    for (vector<T>::const_iterator iter = matrix.begin(); iter != matrix.end(); ++iter) {
        ++printcount;
        cout << setw(12) << *iter;
        outputFile << setw(12) << *iter;
        if (printcount % Columns == 0) {
            cout << endl;
            outputFile << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    outputFile << endl;
    outputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: In what way is it failing?

Comment: "data.txt" is not produced

Comment: Are you sure the method gets called?

Comment: yes, because via cout I see everything on my screen

Comment: try removing the ", ios::app" simply call open on the filename. I believe app assumes the file is already created.

Comment: @pippin1289, no change unfortunately

Comment: have you tried using this argument?std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app   this is how cplusplus.com does it as an example

Comment: @pippin1289 no, how do you mean exactly?

Comment: write this - 

outputFile.open("data.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::app);

Comment: @pippin1289 no change

Comment: How strange, that is all I can think of at the moment. Is the data.txt file even being created?

Comment: no, it is not created and when i create it somewhere in my main i still can't write in it.

Comment: Write a simple program just to create a file. Does that work? What operating system are you on? Does the executable have the permission to create files?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive you're looking for the file in the right place? If you write `outputFile.open("data.txt", ios::out);` and the file isn't created you've got real issues.

Comment: A side note: you don't need to call `open` or `close`. Use the constructor, the destructor will do the close.

Comment: @PeterWood thank you, I made a new member function filemaker, which made a file "test.txt" and since I did that, my write also works(seems strange to me because it has a different filename)

Comment: @Wouter That sounds dubious. Creating one file shouldn't just make it possible to create other files. Maybe you were looking in the wrong place for the file before.